# Errors were encountered while processing: mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server

Tags: 16.04, apt, mysql

Hi get the following error while installing mysql

**sudo apt-get install mysql-server**

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-azure-cloud-tools-4.13.0-1012 linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-1012-azure
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/18.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 160 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 143619 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
(Reading database ... 143774 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
insserv: warning: script 'ehcp_daemon.py' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'ehcp' missing LSB tags and overrides
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I have also tried the solution in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763534/cannot-reinstall-mysql-server-after-its-purge) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805364/dpkg-always-try-to-install-mysql-server-5-7)

The status of the mysql packages are
**dpkg -l | grep mysql**

```
ii  mysql-client-5.7                    5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    amd64        MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-client-core-5.7               5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    amd64        MySQL database core client binaries
ii  mysql-common                        5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
iU  mysql-server                        5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
iF  mysql-server-5.7                    5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-5.7               5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                    amd64        MySQL database server binaries
ii  php5.6-mysql                        5.6.35-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1      amd64        MySQL module for PHP
```

Although these errors occur I am able to login into MySQL. Is it OK to continue with these errors? Please help me with this.